# How do i add text before footer in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

text just before the footer. I'm not a coder so please help me out and suggest me how to do it?

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: if you create dynamic widget into your functions.php and call the widget where you want to use and add the text backend it will be easily shown on where you want, if you ready to do this I can easily suggest you like  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376467/add-phone-number-on-top-of-menu-and-should-be-responsive-view-in-mobile/44382428?noredirect=1#comment75795846_44382428somthing this?

Answer (score 3):

There are many way to add text or whatever in footer,

1. You can find the template file belongs to this page and then find
   footer file which is included using "get_footer()" in the last of
   template file and modify this footer file as you want.
2. Another method is to use hook
   use [wp_footer()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer) hook in your functions.php

   ```
   function add_footer_text_function() {
       echo '<p>Text in Footer<strong>Company name</strong></p>';
   }
   add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_footer_text_function');
   ```
3. As you said you are not a coder then use [Custom Headers and
   Footers](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-headers-and-footers/) plugin using this you can modify footer of your website.

Comment: thanks ganesh but my problem is i want different content for different pages (for seo purpose) above footer

Comment: It can be done easily but you have to put code inside of your functions.php file and use if conditions( check for is page ABC and echo text for page ABC) for every page inside the above function.

Comment: Ganesh can you help me in doing that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**wp_footer**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer) hook.

```
function your_function() {
    echo '<p>This is inserted at the bottom</p>';
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'your_function', 100 );
```

---

For Different page diffrent content you can use [**is_page**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) function.

When any single Page is being displayed.

```
is_page();
```

When Page 42 (ID) is being displayed.

```
is_page( 42 );
```

When the Page with a post_title of "Contact" is being displayed.

```
is_page( 'Contact' );
```

When the Page with a post_name (slug) of "about-me" is being displayed.

```
is_page( 'about-me' );
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```
function your_function() {
    if(is_page( 42 )){ // Enter your page ID
        echo '<p>This is inserted at the bottom</p>';
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'your_function', 100 );
```

Add above code in your active theme `functions.php`.

Comment: thanks but i want different content for different pages . not the same content on every page

Comment: @faizan I have update mu answer. Would you check it?

Comment: Thanks Purvik, as far as i understood that I have to enter this code for every single page in my fnctions.php file, am I right?

Comment: problem: when iam entering this code the text goes to the last bottom but i want it to be above footer ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Advanced Custom Fields plugin and then use this function. Also you need to create a field something like "custom_text".

```
function your_function() {
the_field('custom_text');
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'your_function', 100 );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to go in any complexity, it's super easy. Just go to footer.php and echo your code code before the footer tag.

Example

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[instagram-feed]'); ?>
```